# how to insert values from different tables?

Tags: mysql, php

**I am having a trouble from inserting values from these two tables. I have the personal, honor, and parent table.**

**Personal Table consist of:**

- ExamineeID
- FirstName
- MiddleName
- LastName
- Age
- HomeAddress
- Contact Number
- LastSchoolAttended
- Strand
- SchoolAddress
- Adviser

**Honor Table consist of:**

- HonorID
- Honor1
- Honor2
- Honor3
- Honor4
- ExamineeID (FK Referenced by Personal Table)

**Parent Table consist of:**

- ParentID
- Father
- EducationalFather
- Mother
- EducationalMother
- Guardian
- Occupation
- ExamineeID (FK Referenced by Personal Table)

This is my code:

```
else{


        $sql = "SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, LastSchoolAttended From personal Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ? Limit 1";
        $sqlhonor = "SELECT Honor1, Honor2, Honor3, Honor4 From honor Where Honor1 = ? And Honor2 = ? And Honor3 = ? And Honor4 = ? Limit 0";
        $sqlparent = "SELECT Father, EducationalFather, Mother, EducationalMother, Guardian, Occupation From parent Where Father = ? And EducationalFather = ? And Mother = ? And EducationalMother = ? AND Guardian = ? AND Occupation = ? Limit 0";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)); {

        $INSERTpersonal = "INSERT INTO personal (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, HomeAddress, ContactNumber, LastSchoolAttended, Strand, SchoolAddress, Adviser) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt -> bind_param("ssss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt -> num_rows;

        if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conn -> prepare($INSERTpersonal);
            $stmt -> bind_param("sssisissss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Age,$HomeAddress,$ContactNumber,$LastSchoolAttended,$Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser);
            $stmt -> execute(); 
        }
    }
     if ($stmthonor = $conn->prepare($sqlhonor)) {
                $INSERThonor = "INSERT INTO honor (Honor1,Honor2,Honor3,Honor4) values (?,?,?,?)";
                $stmthonor -> bind_param("ssss", $Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
                $stmthonor -> execute();
                $stmthonor -> bind_result($Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
                $stmthonor -> store_result();
                $rnum = $stmthonor -> num_rows;

            if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmthonor->close();
            $stmthonor = $conn -> prepare($INSERThonor);
            $stmthonor -> bind_param ("ssss", $Honor1, $Honor2, $Honor3, $Honor4);  
            $stmthonor -> execute();    
        }
    }

        if ($stmtparent = $conn -> prepare ($sqlparent)) {
            $INSERTparent = "INSERT INTO parent (Father, EducationalFather,Mother,EducationalMother,Guardian,Occupation) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmtparent -> bind_param("ssssss", $Father,$EducationalFather,$Mother,$EducationalMother, $Guardian, $Occupation);
            $stmtparent -> execute();
            $stmtparent -> bind_result($Father,$EducationalFather,$Mother,$EducationalMother,$Guardian ,$Occupation );
            $stmtparent -> store_result();
            $rnum = $stmtparent -> num_rows;

            if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmtparent->close();
            $stmtparent = $conn -> prepare($INSERTparent);  
            $stmtparent -> bind_param ("ssssss", $Father, $EducationalFather, $Mother, $EducationalMother, $Guardian, $Occupation); 
            $stmtparent -> execute();
        }
    }
```

}

I changed the code and I am having an error like this **Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentsinformation`.`honor`, CONSTRAINT `honor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ExamineeID`) REFERENCES `personal` (`ExamineeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php(74): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php on line 74**

Comment: The use of preprared statemenst is a very good idea, but ti analyze it is ncessary to know the exact error, So please add a error managemen, to see what mysql doesn't like.

Comment: It doesn't show an error. I just add the mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

Comment: try bthge query in phpmyadmin or workbench. If that isn't  a problem. I would check the mysql error log and finally enable general log to see what reaches the server.

Comment: I tried the query by built-in and it worked.

Comment: INSERTpersonal  has ten parameters and you give it "ssss", this must give an error. Please give every query as much parameters as you enetrerd questuionmarks

Comment: I based it on my select query that's why it only has 4 param. I separated the query for select and for the insert. 4 param for select, and 10 for the insert

Comment: As you see in the error message you have a foreign key, so so you have first to enter a personal (ExamineeID) and after that enter the ExamineeID in your table.

Comment: I have my record on my ExamineeID but the other info doesn't distributed at all on their own respective tables and doesn't read my ExamineeID. Only the personal table have a record.

Comment: Ar some point you have to get the ExamineeID before you add to honor and parent. So something like https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php  when the re is no examinee or the catpotred id from the select statement and you have to add to your both insert columns another column ExamineeID  so that your query run

Comment: I tried inserting the ExamineeID to the honor table but now, I am receiving an error that the Column ExamineeID cannot be null

`$INSERThonor = "INSERT INTO honor (Honor1,Honor2,Honor3,Honor4, ExamineeID) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

if ($rnum == 0 ) { 
    $stmthonor->close();
    $stmthonor = $conn -> prepare($INSERThonor);
    $stmthonor -> bind_param ("ssssi", $Honor1, $Honor2, $Honor3, $Honor4, $ExamineeID); 
    $stmthonor -> execute(); 
   }`

Comment: before you make your if ($stmthonor = $conn->prepare($sqlhonor))  you st set $ExamineeID with an actual Id from the table personal then you are at your goal.

Comment: It's usually a bad schema design to have a list of things (Honors) spread across columns.  Have one per row.